# Allocating memory to a pointer giving as argument inside a function

Tags: c, malloc, strlen, c-strings

I want to write a function that can copy the content of a c-string to another c-string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void copy(char*,char*);
int main(){
    char* string = "hello";
    char* destination;

    copy(destination,string);
    printf("Source: %s\nDestination: %s",string,destination);

    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
void copy(char* dest, char* src){
    dest = malloc(strlen(src)*sizeof(char)); //Crashes

    while (*src){
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }   
}
```

Allocating the memory inside the function makes the program crash while allocating the memory before the function call works:

```
char* destination = malloc(strlen(string)*sizeof(char)); //works
```

Comment: *Hint:* look at `memcpy` or use `strdup` Also, btw, add 1 to the length of string otherwise ...

Comment: Strlen()+1 to store \0

Comment: If you are not returning a value, you will need to pass `char **dest` in order to have the new starting address for `dest` available in `main`. ( e.g. `void copy(char **dest, char *src)` and then call `copy (&destination,string);` )

Comment: One does not "allocate memory to a pointer". One allocates memory, and then saves its address in a pointer variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `copy` takes to addresses - the current value of `destination` and the value of `source`.

Then it overwrites the current value of `destination` with the result of `malloc`.

The copy then occurs, and the `malloc`ed memory gets lost.

Either return the value of `destination` from copy, rather than pass it in.

or use `char **` and *.

```
char * copy( char* src){
    char * dest = malloc( (1+strlen(src))*sizeof(char)); //Crashes
    char * toReturn = dest;

    while (*src){
        *dest++ = *src++;
    } 
  return toReturn;
}
```

or

```
void copy( char ** dest, char* src){
     /* overwrite pointer value with the result of malloc */
    char * toCopy;
    (*dest) = malloc((1+strlen(src))*sizeof(char)); //Crashes
    toCopy = *dest;
    while (*src){
        *toCopy++ = *src++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Neither of the solutions you posted are elegant or recommended. In the second solution, you're making use of a `char **` quite unnecessarily. In the first solution, you're mallocing within the function and returning that pointer. Is the caller supposed to free it? Hopefully they do. However, it's not recommended to split up the responsibility that way when you could much more easily pass in the pointer as an argument.

Comment: Understood - was hoping to explain how to get the function to work, not how to design a function correctly.  Although my first is `strdup`, and your recommendation for second is `strcpy`.  Not sure I would have helped as much if I said use `strdup`, `strcpy`

Comment: Don't you need to NUL-terminate the strings?

Answer (score 3):

The primary issue, that has been explained in several different ways, has to do with how you pass `dest` to `copy()`. When you pass a pointer to a function, e.g.:

```
void copy(char* dest, char* src) {
```

The function receives a **copy** of the pointer, which will point to the same address, but **will have a different address of its own**. So when you pass `char *dest`, the `copy()` function receives a *copy* of the `dest` pointer. When you then allocate `dest` in `copy()`, the caller `main()` has no idea what the address for `dest` is in `copy()` and no way of accessing the memory as returned by `dest = malloc(strlen(src)*sizeof(char));` in `copy()`.

Whenever you allocate memory in a function, if you are not *returning* the address for the newly allocated block of memory, you must pass the **address of** the pointer to the function (not a copy of the pointer). That way when you call `malloc`, you are assigning the return of `malloc` (the start address for the new block of memory) as the value of the pointer **at the same address** as in `main()`.

If you remember nothing else, remember that rule: *If you are allocating memory for a pointer you pass to the function, you must either* **(1)** return the new address to the caller; or **(2)** pass the address of the pointer to the function for allocation.

Here is another example along similar lines with a few different approaches:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copy (char **dest, char *src);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *str = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : 
                "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
    char *dest = NULL;

    copy (&dest, str);

    printf ("\n str  : %s\n dest : %s\n\n", str, dest);

    free (dest); /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}

void copy (char **dest, char *src)
{
    if (!src) {     /* validate src string */
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid string 'src'.\n",
                __func__);
        return;
    }

    size_t len = 0;
    char *p = src;

    for (;*p; p++, len++) {}    /* strlen */

    /* allocate and validate -- every time */
    if (!(*dest = malloc (len * sizeof **dest + 1))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n",
                __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    p = *dest;  /* copy src to dest */
    for (; *src; src++) *p++ = *src;
    *p = 0;     /* null-terminate   */
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/copystr

 str  : A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 dest : A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

**Note:** if you are not using `gcc` then change `__func__` to the function name.

Answer (score 2):

In your `main()` function you are declaring a variable `destination` of type `char *` without initializing it. You then pass `destination` as an argument to your `copy()` function. It's important to understand what data is being passed to `copy()`. In this case, since `destination` has not been initialized, we don't know what is being passed to `copy()`. This is fine when you `malloc()` before the function call because, in that scenario, `destination` has been initialized. In particular, its value is some address in the heap that was returned by `malloc()`.

As others have noted, you should also be careful to allocate 1 byte more than the src string length in order to allow space for the null-terminator.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand what I did wrong on my first try !

Comment: Despite some other answers/comments on here, please know that your first attempt (with malloc'ing in main) is the more elegant way of approaching this problem.